# Refresh page by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, c3.js

for example i have an element in html file

```
<div id="dateRange">1d</div>
```

Which control by a javascript function

```
    $("#30Days").click(function(){
     $(".dateRange").html("30d");
     });

    $("#12Weeks").click(function(){
     $(".dateRange").html("12w");
     });

    $("#12Months").click(function(){
     $(".dateRange").html("12m");
     });
```

And i got an chart built by c3.js

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto:"#date",
        data: {
                //some config
            });
```

And now i want the chart reload by ajax when a user onclick `<div id="dateRange">1d</div>` how my i do that? Is there any example?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I see `Flush` located here:  http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-flush  looks like this will force the chart to be redrawn.  Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: `chart.load()` using AJAX on some Event or Timer. Do you understand AJAX?

Comment: `load` located here:  http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load an example of it here:  http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html  The whole point of AJAX is so that you don't need to refresh the page, so if you want to refresh the page, no need to use AJAX at all.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at the documentation it looks like you should be using the `load` method.

```js
$.ajax({
  // the ajax request for data
  success: function(data) {
    // format the data
    chart.load(data)
  }
})
```

Take a look at the documentation http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

Is ajax call necessary?
You can do like these.

HTML:

```
<div id="dateRange" onclick="return RefreshChart(event)">1d</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function RefreshChart(elem){
   chart.load({
    url: 'PathToFetchData'
   });
}
```

comment it, if you have any query.